# In "会很 <adj.> 的"， is 很 meaningless?

Tags: grammar

会~的 explains the future event that will happen.

```
她肯定会很高兴的。
She will be (very) happy.
```

Is that 的 a collaboration of 会~的?(很 does NOT mean 'very', like 我很好)
or just associated with the adjective 高兴？ (很 does mean 'very')

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: 很 **does** mean very here. 会~的 like you said is a construct to represent `will xxx`.  The same sentence could be written `她肯定会高兴的` she will be happy. Different, obviously, from the sentence you gave: 她肯定会很高兴的。She will be very happy.

Comment: @user330635 you should put this down as an answer rather than comment... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to put down user330635's comment down as an answer, since wasn't sure the other answer addressed the question correctly.

In the sentence:

**她肯定会(很)高兴的。**

The use of the word 很 is to indicate the degree of the adjective 高兴.

**She will be (very) happy.**

Without it the sentence just suggest that the person will be happy, but we do not know if she will be mildly pleased or extremely pleased about something.

Comment: Well, the question was basically answered in the comment, so I was just putting it in the appropriate place for future reference :p

Answer (score 4):

I don't know exactly what do you mean by "meaningless", but the sentence would definitely sound weird without “很”. (I wouldn't really use the word "meaningless", because basically every character in Chinese comes with a certain "meaning", no?)

“的” is necessary in this constellation with “会”.

```
她肯定很高兴。
She is for sure very happy.
```

or

```
她肯定会很高兴的。
She would for sure be very happy.
```

I'd say the first sentence is less common compared to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

很 is a adv which be used to describe the level of adj word.You can say 很快，means very fast.It is  equal of very.
会，in some conditions, means be sure to,equalling the word will.
的 is a affix in Chinese.It can be added after a noun to construct a adj.For example,we can say 布的 to describe something made by cloth,but in oral Chinese,的 is omited normally.